# How to handle the situation with sudden termination of PHP Script?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I wrote a php script to create the create the random data entry for the one table from another in MYSQL. I used while loop for the insert operation. The loop count nearly 1600 but the script terminated automatically after some 250 or 333 loop count without any error. What's the cause for these kind of problem.What may be the solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should give your code so we can find error. And what is "sudden termination": is it end of loop or end of script?

Comment: can you share your code?why you need 1600 insertion?

Comment: Sever memory overflow?

Comment: Sudden termination means its happening on different level and timing . Is not in end of loop or end of the script

Comment: me too thinking on it may be Server memory overflow problem. How i conform it and solve. @sdespont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to the beginning of your script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

If you are running the script from the console, like if you ssh into the server and run:

```
php my_script.php
```

then it should tell you the problem right away, now it could be that you are running the script by fetching a webpage (like http://www.myserver.com/my_script.php), on that case you need to have in mind that most web servers puts a timeout over the scripts (like 60 or 90 seconds) and after that timeout, it just kills the scripts because it thinks that's there is something wrong going with the script, so it mostly depends on your server configuration

---

So the problem is the timeout, you can try to add at the beginning of the script:

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

but if the php is configured to run in safe_mode, you cannot update the maximum execution time for the script and unfortunately there is nothing you can do there....

Comment: I used the error handler like below.But i didn't receive any error on this case .                                                     function customError($errno, $errstr)
    {
    echo "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr";
    die();
    }

  //set error handler;
  set_error_handler("customError");

Comment: 1) Did you add the error_reporting flag to display every error-warning on screen, and set the display_errors to 1 so it will show the errors even if the php configuration was setup to not show any errors at all? 2) Are you running the script from a ssh bash, or requesting a webpage?

Comment: Tried with your code . I got Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in 'filepath' on line 84. Thanks for your help. How to resolve this problem ? @rorra

Comment: I just requesting the webpage.

Comment: Updated the answer, if it helped you, remember to give me a positive vote, if you are able to fix your issue with the set_time_limit(0; at the beginning of the script, remember to select my answer as accepted :)